# JQuery Slider min max value changing based on step

Tags: jquery, uislider

I have this problem where I have a set of `min` & `max` value of :

```
min = 1150000
max = 20000000
step = 100000
```

And the result always forcing the max to only be `19950000`, it can't go beyond that and also didn't work as expected. (Expected result is `max = 20000000`)

I know how the `step`, `min`, & `max` work, but is there any workaround to prevent this from happening? (Other than reducing the step or changing any value)

PS:
I already tried to use

```
$( "#price-range" ).slider("values", 0, 1150000)
$( "#price-range" ).slider("values", 1, 20000000);
```

But when I console.log this with `$( "#price-range" ).slider("values")`. The results shown is [1150000, 19950000]. (Expected result is [1150000, 20000000]

Any possible workaround is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a limitation of most slider controls. For both the `min` and `max` values to be selectable, the delta between the values must be divisible by the `step`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, I notice this as well. So might as well assume that there's no other way to bypass this limitation as of now. Thanks for clarifying things!